# Parse from file to dictionary in correct order, in Python

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, dictionary, biopython

I've written some code to parse an EMBL file and dump specific regions of the file into a dictionary.

The keys of the dictionary correlate to the label of a specific region that I want to capture and each key's value is the region itself.

I have then created another function to write the contents of the dictionary to a text file.

However, I have found that the text file contains the information in a different order to that found in the original EMBL file.

I can't figure out why it is doing this - is it because dictionaries are unordered? Is there any way around it?

```
from Bio import SeqIO

s6633 = SeqIO.read("6633_seq.embl", "embl")

def make_dict_realgenes(x):
    dict = {}
    for i in range(len(x.features)):
        if x.features[i].type == 'CDS':
            if 'hypothetical' not in x.features[i].qualifiers['product'][0]:
                try:
                    if x.features[i].location.strand == -1:
                        x1 = x.features[i].location.end
                        y1 = x1 + 30
                        dict[str(x.features[i].qualifiers['product'][0])] =\
                             str(x[x1:y1].seq.reverse_complement())
                    else:
                        x2 = x.features[i].location.start
                        y2 = x2 - 30
                        dict[x.features[i].qualifiers['product'][0]] =\
                             str(x[y2:x2].seq)
                except KeyError:
                    if x.features[i].location.strand == -1:
                        x1 = x.features[i].location.end
                        y1 = x1 + 30
                        dict[str(x.features[i].qualifiers['translation'][0])] =\
                             str(x[x1:y1].seq.reverse_complement())
                    else:
                        x2 = x.features[i].location.start
                        y2 = x2 - 30
                        dict[x.features[i].qualifiers['translation'][0]] =\
                             str(x[y2:x2].seq)
    return dict

def rbs_file(dict):
    list = []
    c = 0
    for k, v in dict.iteritems():
        list.append(">" + k + " " + str(c) + "\n" + v + "\n")
        c = c + 1

    f = open("out.txt", "w")
    a = 0
    for i in list:
        f.write(i)
        a = a + 1

    f.close()
```

Comment: Yes, dictionaries are unordered. If order is important, use a `list` or `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve order in a dictionary, use an `OrderedDict` from `collections`. Try Changing the top of your code to this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from Bio import SeqIO

s6633 = SeqIO.read("6633_seq.embl", "embl")

def make_dict_realgenes(x):
    dict = OrderedDict()   
...
```

Also, I would advise against overwriting the builtin 'dict' if you can easily rename it.

Answer (score 0):

I slightly refactored your code, and I suggest to write the output as is produced while parsing the file, instead of relaying in OrderedDicts.

```
from Bio import SeqIO


output = open("out.txt", "w")

for seq in SeqIO.parse("CP001187.embl", "embl"):
    for feature in seq.features:
        if feature.type == "CDS":
            qualifier = (feature.qualifiers.get("product") or
                         feature.qualifiers.get("translation"))[0]
            if "hypothetical" not in qualifier:
                if feature.location.strand == -1: 
                    x1 = feature.location.end
                    x2 = x1 + 30
                    sequence = seq[x1:x2].seq.reverse_complement()
                else:
                    x1 = feature.location.start
                    x2 = x1 - 30
                    sequence = seq[x2:x1].seq

                output.write(">" + qualifier + "\n")
                output.write(str(sequence) + "\n")

                # You can always insert here to the OrderedDict anyway, e.g.
                # d[qualifier] = str(sequence)

output.close()
```

In python only rarely `for i in range(len(anything))` is the way to go.

---

There is also a cleaner way to output your sequences using Biopython. Use a list to append the Seqs, instead of a dict or OrderedDict:

```
from Bio.SeqRecord import SeqRecord

my_seqs = []

# Each time you generate a sequence, instead of writing to a file
# or inserting in dict, do this:
my_seqs.append(SeqRecord(sequence, id=qualifier, description=""))

 # Now you have the my_seqs, they can be writen in a single line:
SeqIO.write(my_seqs, "output.fas", "fasta")
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! What's wrong with `for i in range(len(anything))`, though?

Comment: It's not pythonic. If you want to cycle elements, use `for element in list_of_elements`. If you need an index, use `for i, element in enumerate(list_of_elements)`. Also other reasons, like "list_of_element" doesn't have to have a length if it's a generator. http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201407/creative_looping.html